# CLion 2018.1 compatibility with C++17

Tags: c++17, clion

After a recent upgrade of my Cmake project from C++ 17 from C++ 14, CLion was unable to resolve function calls made on pointers; however, it was still able to resolve function calls on objects.  I have reset every possible cache and even done a clean install of the software; however, the IDE does not seem to be able to clear this issue.  Is there a fundamental compatibility issue with CLion 2018.1 and C++17?

Comment: Have you upgraded to [2018.1.1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2018/04/clion-2018-1-1-update-is-available/)? How about the [2018.1.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2018/04/clion-2018-1-2-eap/) early access preview? If those still have problems parsing your code, then create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and report it on [their issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP) (or at least search for the issue to see if it's already reported).

Answer (score 0):

After installing the early access preview of 2018.1.2, the resolution issues with pointer function calls have been fixed; however, it seems there are still issues with function calls with arguments that are `std::optional`, it seems any issues with language comprehension are due to C++ 17 and will likely be addressed in future releases.